# Какую базу данных использовать в фреймворка Django

Tags: python, django, pgadmin4

У меня такой вопрос. Какую лучше использовать БД для хранении пользователей, встроенную или лучше подключить внешнюю например pgAdmin 4.
Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Нет никакой встроенной базы данных. Официально Django [поддерживает](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/databases/) следующие:

- [PostgreSQL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/databases/#postgresql-notes)
- [MariaDB](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/databases/#mariadb-notes)
- [MySQL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/databases/#mysql-notes)
- [Oracle](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/databases/#oracle-notes)
- [SQLite](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/databases/#sqlite-notes)

Также [существуют](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/databases/#using-a-3rd-party-database-backend) базы данных, поддерживаемые третьими лицами:

- [CockroachDB](https://pypi.org/project/django-cockroachdb/)
- [Firebird](https://pypi.org/project/django-firebird/)
- [Google Cloud Spanner](https://pypi.org/project/django-google-spanner/)
- [Microsoft SQL Server](https://pypi.org/project/mssql-django/)
- [TiDB](https://pypi.org/project/django-tidb/)
- [YugabyteDB](https://pypi.org/project/django-yugabytedb/)

---

По умолчанию используется SQLite. Но вы можете использовать любую другую из списка. По моим наблюдениям, PostgreSQL — наиболее популярная